# How to convert text inserted into textformfield into image in a flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am having Textformfield where user can type text and on a button tap i want to convert inserted text into image and display it on a some other screen.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I tried using third party [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package but i want it without third party package or API

Answer (score 4):

You can get an image of some widget by finding widget's `RenderObject` and converting it to an image. Then you can save this image in the state and use in other places.

Below is an example:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final GlobalKey _globalKey = GlobalKey();
  Widget? _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          if (_image != null) _image!,
          RepaintBoundary(
            key: _globalKey,
            child: TextField(),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final boundary = _globalKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
              if (boundary is RenderRepaintBoundary) {
                final uiimage = await boundary.toImage();
                final pngBytes = await uiimage.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

                setState(() {
                  _image = Image.memory(
                      Uint8List.view(pngBytes!.buffer)
                  );
                });
              }
            },
            child: Text('Cheese'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```